# Fancy triangle between sections on most of startup pages?

Tags: html, css

On most startup pages, like [this one](http://skyflavour.com/)  (the error message from sever), I see a fancy triangle that seperates section divs. Is it using any bootstrap components or people do it manually?

How to make this nice triangle?

[image]

Comment: http://skyflavour.com seems to be offline.

Comment: I've added a screenshot from the website. Please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to get better answers.

Comment: What is a "startup page", exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a triangle is possible with CSS.

[cssarrowplease.com](http://cssarrowplease.com/) (Have a look at this service, it will help you create these with ease!)

A sample code similar to the one you have mentioned :

```
.arrow_box {
    position: relative;
    background: #ffffff;
}
.arrow_box:after {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS triangles are actually very simple!

Here is a great tutorial on it: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/